# How to restart Flutter app on android without closing and opening the app again?

Tags: flutter

How to restart Flutter app on android without closing and opening the app again?

i use these
MyApp.restartApp() and SystemNavigator.pop()

but the problem is that it is not user friendly, me too as i develope the application closing and re opening the app is bit anoying.

i dont know the proper term on what my point is but you may get my idea.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix

Answer (score 2):

Try this: I use this when i need to restart app for example internet is restored after being down

in your main

```
runApp(const RestartWidget(child: const MyApp()));
```

create restart widget

```
class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = UniqueKey();

  void restartApp() {
    setState(() {
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyedSubtree(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

then in your main add this

```
runApp(const RestartWidget(child: const MyApp()));
```

Then to trigger restart say in a button

```
onTap: (){
    RestartWidget.restartApp(context);
               },
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try this one later., but i think that function does the same with MyApp.restartApp or .pop, which is it closes the app and then you need to open up again so that it will refresh?. Asume that it is published i dont want the user to, in order to clear the current logs or a data that users input the app needs to close and re open again. I think i cant realy explain it , btw im a newbe, i really appreciate your coment sir

Comment: So you want the app to clear logs and restart? Cause the method I created was to avoid libraries and customized mine where it just restarts the app from the start. So you can add another method within the function to clear data/logs on restart

Comment: no sir this is the situation of my app, my app, is an uber clone i took a course on udemy buth the instructor did not fix it yet. in the app if i book a ride it shows the available driver for example one driver available, now if i change my mind and go back to the main screen and book a difrent place for example and press the book button the current available driver that is available in the first booking it just duplicated imean it shows two driver but it only duplicated the first driver. doing it again and it just increasing the displayed driver. in order to fix it the user need to press

Comment: press the x button and what it does is it closes the app and user need to open it again,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) package can be helpful.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -3):

If you're in your IDE, while your app is running you can try to perfom a **Hot Restart** of a **Hot Reload** by pressing **r** or **R** keys.